# Mail sent by mail function marked as spam

Tags: php

I'm using the `mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)` function to send emails from my website to a certain email but it keeps going into the spam folder.

Is there any way to fix that?how can I make my message reliable so it won't concidered as spam?since it's not!

Comment: You need to show headers of received message. Does your message contain links?

Comment: That's my email header:    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

Comment: `mail` function most of the times treated this way, because it's not sent from a real email address.

Comment: And this email_from is real email address on real server that is running on same ip as php? if not, this is the problem.

Comment: We don't use X-Mailer:.

Comment: All the mail services have different, often proprietary algorithms for spam detection. Your best bet is to get your site popular without `mail` and hope the e-mail services whitelist you/improve chances of not being marked spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many variables to fully eliminate this. The problem that you face is that today's email filters are very efficient at their job. One of the shortcomings of course is that sometimes they filter out email which is not spam. That having been said, it's quite subjective - you might think that the email your site is sending out to someone is critical, but I might not. I'd probably consider it spam, depending upon its contents.

It depends upon the content of your email (text vs HTML, sensitive words like "unsubscribe"), the server upon which the site is hosted, and the destination of the mail. Unfortunately, there's little you can do in terms of **guaranteeing** delivery to their inbox (rather than spam folder), which is why most sites add a caveat these days, warning users to check their spam folders.

Comment: Yes it's a spam as sent by a machine automatically.